# Create interactive plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, raster, shapefile

I wonder if it is possible in R (RStudio) to have an interactive plot where user clicks in an image and this is used as input for upcoming processing. Here is my situation:

I have a raster that I plot

```
plot(NDVI[[4]])
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Afterwards, I add a second layer containing polygon limits:

```
plot(fields, add=TRUE)
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

My objective is that user clicks on the image to select some of these polygons (let's say 3). Those clicks are used to identify those polygons which will later be used to derive the mean raster value inside the area they represent.

So far, I have been doing so updating a shapefile containing points, but I would like to make more interactive

```
points<-readOGR("Points_crops.shp") 
fields<-readOGR("Boundaries.shp")
fields_sub <- fields[!is.na(sp::over(fields, sp::geometry(points))), ]
NDVI_mean<-lapply(NDVI, FUN=function (NDVI) {data.frame(mean=extract(NDVI,fields_sub,fun=mean))})
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it'd help you, but take a look at the [mapview](https://r-spatial.github.io/mapview/reference/index.html) package.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Did not know this package and I have found couple of functions that will help me in other projects :)

Comment: @patL, in case you have experience with `mapview::cubeview()`, can you have a look to this? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54553138/rgb-colors-in-a-raster-cub-visualization-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those interested, I have solved the issue using the `click` function. This will retrieve the coordinates of the point you click with the mouse. After that, you can convert them to `spatialPoints` setting a `proj4string` (same as the one of the raster of reference).

```
  points<-click(NDVI[[4]], n=5, xy=TRUE, show=TRUE)
  points$value<-NULL
  points<-SpatialPoints(points, proj4string = crs(S2_stack_crop[[2]]))
```

Once I have the points as `spatialPoints` I can continue with the next step